# Error a la hora de cambiar tamaño imagen en LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

he creado un ForEach para recorrertodos los archivos en mi base de datos, esto con el fin de cambiarle el tamaño a los nuevos que van a ingresar y a los que y estan en la base de datos. Pero me arroja un error al quererla guardar. Dejo la funcion donde hago est proceso. Saludos

```
$imagenes   = $request->file('archivos');


  $path       = "./files/";

  foreach ($imagenes as $imagen) {

    $filename = time() . $imagen->getClientOriginalName() . '.' . $imagen->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $ext      = File::extension($filename);

    switch ($ext)
    {
      case "jpg":
        Image::make($imagen)->resize(380, 600)->save($path . $filename );
      break;
      case "png":
        Image::make($imagen)->resize(380, 600)->save($path . $filename );
      break;
      default:
        $imagen->move($path, $filename);
      break;
    }
```

Comment: Cual es el error que te sale?

Comment: Simplementeno no guarda la imagen

Comment: y si cambias la path por $path=public_path().'/files/'

Comment: ¿porqué no usas el facade de Storage para guardar los archivos?